# Simple load, count and process form

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, loading, progress

I need some help with a script I am developing. I have some advertisements.
When a user clicks on the advertisement, a new page will open up.

On that new page, there will be an div for status messages, and below that div a big iframe.

I want it like this:
 1. In the status message box, it should say "Loading content of iFrame..." (Until the url of the iFrame has been fully loaded)
 2. It should countdown from X seconds / loading bar.
 3. When it hits zero, a form should run, and output data in the status div.

Can someone please help me obtain this? It should all be done with jQuery and without any reloads.

**I HAVE THIS SO FAR:**

```
   var countDownTimer = null;
    var seconds = <?php echo $exposure[$r['exposure']]; ?>;

    function setCountDownTimer(){
      if(countDownTimer)
        clearTimeout(countDownTimer);

      countDownTimer = setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);
    };

    function updateCountdown() {
          countDownTimer = null;
          seconds--;

          if (seconds > 0) {
             $("#countdown").text("You must view this advertisement for " + seconds + " seconds.");
             //$('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: Math.round((seconds/10)*100) });
             setCountDownTimer();
          } else {
             submitForm();
          }
     }

// on document load:
$(function() {

   $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });

   // set "waiting" message:
   $("#loadingStatus").html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");

   // on iframe load:

   $('#iFrame').load(function() {

       $("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());

       //Attached click event to the link inside iframe to restart the timer
       var iframe = $('#iFrame');
       iframe.contents().find("linkSelector").click(function(){  
         window.top.setCountDownTimer();  
       });

   });

   setCountDownTimer();
});



function submitForm() {
                $("#countdown").empty().html('<img src="..ify/dream/images/loading.gif" />');
                $.post(
                    'index.php?i=v&p=k&key=DSF79SADFHSA7D9FGSAD097FSAD7F9779ASDFGS9', 
                    $('form').serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        proccessData(data);
                    }
                ); 

}  

function proccessData (data) {
            $('#statusF').hide().html('');

            if(data=='success'){
                $('form').fadeOut();
                $('#countdown').addClass('noti-success').html('Advertisement validated!').slideDown();
                redirect("?i=l");  
            }
            else {
                $('#countdown').addClass('noti-error').html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        }
```

The problem with the code above, is that when a user for example clicks in the iframe, the status message timer will mess up. So :/

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery.ajax method (or one of its derivatives).  Using jQuery.ajax, you can send whatever data you need to the server to "run a form" (as you mentioned) and when you get html back, you can save it in a variable.  You can then use your timer object to set the html of the div to the new content when the timeout expires.

Comment: Do you have any example of this? I am already using the $post function from jQuery to submit a form, and get the result back.

Comment: You have a callback handler for when $.post succeeds, right?  You get the response from the server as html, right?  You can use $.html to put that html in your div container.